# Wordpress slider plugin with dynamic height

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

Cannot find a plugin for creating slideshow (for posts) in Wordpress. Already tried a couple of dozen.

The need to:

- responsive, auto width (using max-width, i think)
- if img is vertically NOT TO CUT IT! i. e. proportions must be maintained, height varies relative only to the width
- it must be free (or freemium)

Wordpress Guru, if you know about these plugins, answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. If you need good slidedhow with dynamic height in posts use «oik-nivo-slider».